# What are the most used parts of STL?

Tags: c++, stl

What parts of STL (no boost or TR1, please) people still commonly use in their professional as well as personal environments, if any?

These days I find myself using the following:

Containers:

- vector
- set
- map

Iterators:

- const and not for above containers

Functional objects:

- bind1st
- bind2nd

Algorithms:

- find
- find_first_of
- for_each
- swap
- sort

Please not only post a list of STL stuff, but also include your context or example of usage. This way we can all benefit from not just the name but its application.

Comment: Voting to close as this fails the "detailed and specific" constraint from the faq. The STL is a huge library, and I fail to see how a collection of "I use sets to keeps sets of values" answers can be of use.

Comment: I don't see this working other than as a community wiki poll.  That might actually provide useful information.

Comment: How can you fail to see these, if people show examples of their usage and domain where its used, can be very helpful to folks like me to who want to get a good ground of STL in commercial software?  If anything, this question can be designated as wiki..

Comment: make this community wiki. until then, i vote to close too

Comment: @litb changed to community wiki. thx

Comment: Sasha: "Examples" of usage loose all meaning when taken out of the context of the code that they are used in. If most examples in books and tutorials seem contrived, it's because they are. They're contrived because the STL elements are used to solve low level implementation details on larger problems. To understand WHY they're used to solve those problems, you often need to know more about the larger problem. Hence we get contrived textbook samples, a simple problem showing how a specific STL tools solves it, without loosing sight of that STL tool. I severely doubt you'll get good answers.

Comment: Voting to close, these "questions" are noise.

Comment: This question could be useful! @Binary Worrier: No where was it mentioned WHY should one use the STL libraries but rather HOW to use them with an example if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Containers, algorithms and iterators are being used the most, at least as far as I am concerned

Answer (score 1):

I don't use algorithms too much because I don't like the binding and mem_fnc things too much.  I can never get things done without looking up and trying a couple of times and I don't immediately understand constructs with them.
I'm still waiting for C++0x lambda and bind...

Answer (score 0):

I use all but binders. Boost bind is a good alternative.

I rarely use streams. Usually, I need more than the features streaming provide.

I use exceptions as base classes for my own exception types.

In the rest... I use the containers, iterators (sequences) and algorithms as needed.

Answer (score 0):

With remove/erase being a common idiom, I'm using std::remove a lot. I've on more than one occasion used a std::stack to make it clear to future readers what I intended (LIFO container). When I want a FIFO container, I often use std::deque.

Answer (score 0):

I use `std::vector` when I need a collection of stuff and `std::map` when I need an associative array.  I use iterators quite a bit, so I'm really looking forward to the `auto` keyword from C++0x.  I don't use the standard algorithms much beyond `std::for_each`, but that's partly because I'm often calling the member functions `find` and `erase` for `std::map`.